# What is the IIS equivalent of a rewrite rule that sends all requests to a PHP file?

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, iis7, iis, isapi-rewrite

I've always used Apache for all my web development work and I'm struggling to get my head around IIS. I've got an API that re-routes all requests to one particular file: 'api.php', how would I do the following in IIS:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/.* /api.php
```

My server only allows web.config files to achieve this so I have no access to IIS manager, or anything of that nature. I'm using IIS 7.5.

Answer (score 2):

The design pattern you are using is called the "[front controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern)" --  a central entry point for handling requests.

Here is [a website that shows how to implement that pattern with various webservers](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/web_servers.html).  Here is the configuration they recommend for IIS in the *web.config* file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Silex Front Controller" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

**First Method :**

Install web platform installer from:
http://www.iis.net/downloads

Find the urlrewrite and add to IIS, then you can find URL rewrite section in IIS.

You can create a new rule or import from .htaccess file via URL rewrite.

**Second and Easy Method :**

1. Open IIS and select related website
2. Go to errors section and find 404 error.
3. Double click on it.
4. Change URL to `/index.php`

Now all unknown requests redirect to `index.php`.